# RDLC report keeps loading without showing data

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I want to generate a rdlc  report by manually populating values to dataset because I send the date as an input to the query.
I use the following code to do that

```
//my list get populated with the relevant records according to its date and I'm using the tableadapter of my dataset to do that

List<DailySalesEntity> list = DailySalesHandler.GetSalesByDate(dateTimePicker1.Value);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource report = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet_Dailysales", list);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(report);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

.
I’m using a tablix to show my data using the dataset.I have set the correct report to the report viewer.
I don’t get any exceptions. But the report keeps loading and does not show the report. What is it I’m doing wrong.

How can I populate the dataset by passing a parameter to the query, and use the resulting dataset in the report?

Answer (score 14):

I just had this problem and solved it.
The loading sign kept showing and never dissapearing.
In my case the problem was that I wasn't handling the `IsPostBack` value.
The `LocalReport.Refresh()` generates a postback and if not handled, it will keep posting and posting.

This was my problem. By walling Refrеsh the page kept doing PostBacks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Report data source code...
    myReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Report data source code...
        myReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

So, check that you are handling the PostBack and not getting an infinite loop.